# How to Put 3 tabs in a fragment not a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, tabs

I have searched through most of the solutions similar to my problem but still cant solve it because they are all explaining using FragmentActivity. I want if a fragment is called it should show 3 tabs.
Please i want to use fragment but not FragmentActivity.

I will be happy if you can post the Fragment.java source and corresponding the .xml files

Comment: When i run my code it just gives me error and the fragment is not able to start

Comment: Examine the Java stack trace (found in LogCat) to see the error. If you do not understand the error, ask a question in which you post your code and your stack trace to see if somebody can help you.

Comment: ok i will force and add the code